# Regex match text inside *

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that extracts text inside two delimiters, but not if the delimiter occurs multiple times in a row.

For example, I have this text:
`*hi*   *how are you*   **fine** and **you ?**`

I want to match: `hi` and `how are you`

I don't want to match: `fine` and `you ?`, because they include the delimiter two times in a row instead of just one time.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you could just replace the asterisks with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be the following: `/^\*([^\*]+)\*$/`

```
let regex = /^\*([^\*]+)\*$/;

console.info(regex.exec('*hi*'));  // ["*hi*", "hi"]
console.info(regex.exec('*how are you*'));  // ["*how are you*", "how are you"]

console.info(regex.exec('**fine** and **you ?**'));  // null
```

**Explanation:**

- The `^` character marks the beginning of a line (not in the square brackets but right after the slash)
- The `$` character marks the end of a line
- The group `[^\*]+` matches all strings that do not consist of asterisks

Answer (score 0):

Working for me `/[\*\_]{1}([^\*\_]+)[\*\_]{1}/g`

Comment: Why do you use the underscore (`_`) character in your regex? Did I misunderstand your original question?